# Calculate the similarity(through a formula) between two records with a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, similarity

I came up with a formula to calculate the similarity between two records and it is pretty simple

Similarity = No of attributes matched between two records/ Total No of Attributes *100

For Example:

```
ID |First Name| Last Name| DOB       | Parent Last Name
1  |John      |Doe       | 03/19/1989| Jonathan
1  |John      |Doe       | 03/19/1998| Jonathan
```

We Will get a similarity of ¾*100 = 75% for ID=1.

I want to implement this with the help of a SQL query. I am aware that I can do it with a program but I want to try it with a SQL query.

The following steps will calculate this formula.

For all records belonging to a particular ID compare all the attributes and if they match then 1 or else 0.

Get the sum of all the matches for a particular ID.

Calculate the similarity for a given ID.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Note: I am using SQL server 2008.

Comment: Is every `ID` supposed to have 2 rows?. If there can be more, then do you need to compare everyone and see if all of them are identical to assign the value `1`?

Comment: Yes. There can be more than 2 but not less than 2. Also, Yes we will need to compare all the records for an ID and then assign 1 if they match or else 0. even if one of them doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, you are trying to do an "intra-ID" similarity on the records.  Here is one way:

```
select id,
       ((case when min(FirstName) = max(FirstName) then 1.0 else 0 end) +
        (case when min(LastName) = max(LastName) then 1.0 else 0 end) +
        (case when min(DOB) = max(DOB) then 1.0 else 0 end) +
        (case when min(ParentLastName) = max(ParentLastName) then 1.0 else 0 end)
       ) / 4.0 as similarity
from t
group by id;
```

This ignores NULL values.

Comment: Will it give the value 1 if it ignores on null values?

Comment: @John Yup, since it's using aggregation functions. Pretty clever, actually, and you could use `ISNULL` and some dummy value if you want this to behave different

Comment: @Lamak I agree. However, When two values are null it is not matching it and assigning a value of 0.

Comment: @John Then you can use `ISNULL` as I said before. For instance, for `FirstName` you can do: `CASE WHEN MIN(ISNULL(FirstName,'')) = MAX(ISNULL(FirstName,''))....`